# Spring Server Sent Events

Tags: spring, internet-explorer, server-sent-events

I use SseEmitter to achieve streaming using "Server-Sent Events", and have been successful doing it in Chrome, and Firefox browsers. But have been unsuccessful doing the same in IE. I know SSE does not work on IE browser, but have seen it could be leverages using concept of Polyfill.

I am trying to use Polyfill, with Spring SseEmitter but it's not working. Any idea how can I integrate Spring SseEmitter with IE browser?

Comment: Might be helpful to list which polyfill you are using, which version of IE (e.g. IE10, IE11, Edge, etc.), and in what way it is not working. (e.g. Does IE come with a debug console, so you can see network activity. That should tell you if it is making the connection, if any data is arriving, etc.)

Comment: BTW, I see under the latest Microsoft browser, SSE support has crawled as far as "Under Consideration". https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/serversenteventseventsource/  It looks to be 4th or 5th most requested. If you know how to vote, worth voting for!